# How to update (or CRUD) products (or entries) via API?

Tags: plugins, api

I want to update certain fields of a product (or entry) from a 3rd party.

I see some talk about plugins and some refer to [this .all talk about Creating a RESTful API with Craft 3](https://dotall.com/sessions/how-to-create-a-full-rest-api-with-craft-3).

I found the [Craft CMS Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api), but it seems to be a way to create a read-only API.

How can I update a product's fields from a 3rd party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tl;dr:** Mutations in GraphQL seems to be the way to go - <del>but GraphQL in Craft doesn't yet support mutations on Commerce elements. As for now, you have to create a Craft CMS Plugin.</del> [Follow the progress of mutations support on GitHub](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/1092)

**Alternative 1 (sort of)**

According to [#9667](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/27621/9667) - the 3rd party [CraftQL-plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/craftql) lets you do CRUD on everything* via [Mutations](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations) (GraphQL way of altering data) - so that's an alternative while we wait to the native GraphQL functionality to support Mutations (see https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4835 for status on that one. It's a part of the 4.0 milestone)

Also, Pixel & Tonic has [added support for Mutations to the 4.0 milestone](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4835) for Craft CMS on the built in GraphQL plugin. So it's coming.

* Well, not *everything*. CraftQL supports the following entities: entries, sites, draft, assets, globals, tags and users. The documentation contains a section about [third-party field support](https://github.com/markhuot/craftql#third-party-field-support) that probably lets you implement support for mutating Craft Commerce-fields and other 3rd party fields.

I've added a Feature Request on Craft Commerce [regarding GraphQL and mutations](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/1092). Let's see what they answer.

**Alternative 2 (only real alternative in 2019)**

Also, if you can't wait for mutations in Craft Commerce, you can create your own Craft Plugin. Have a look at my question "[How to accept incoming Webhooks](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32978/how-to-accept-incoming-webhooks)", which helps you along with creating a plugin that can do things like creating and modifying products in Craft.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the capabilities of the 3rd party. Assuming they have the ability to trigger an http request to your Craft site, you would typically point that request to a custom controller action to trigger whatever updates you need based on the http post data.

You'll probably need to build some kind of authentication, such as checking a secret code sent by the third-party, or something more robust such as JSON Web Tokens.

The Craft 3 docs around controllers are pretty lacking at the time of writing IMO, but the V2 docs can get you most of the way there: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/controllers.html

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html

Comment: So far Craft CMS has surprised me time after time with its functionality and simplicity - but now I became a little disappointed. So what you are saying is that there is no first party API with authentication in Craft? (it would make sense to re-use the existing authentication module)