# How to accept incoming webhooks?

Tags: api, plugin-webhooks

I've tested the [webhooks plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/webhooks). Awesome. Works brilliantly.

How how about incoming webhooks? What if my 3rd party ERP system has changes that it wants to put into my Craft site. How do I go about getting the changes into Craft?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nitech from the future. You need to read up a bit. While you built RC Planes from FliteTest with your kids, I went ahead and read up a bit for you:

**Webhooks is a concept, not a technology**

[Webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) are to apps what push notifications are to us. Remember when you had to check your email to know if there was a new mail? Not any more. Technically speaking, webhooks are ["user-defined callbacks made with HTTP"](https://zapier.com/blog/what-are-webhooks/). They are usually triggered by some event happening in the source app.

Nitech, you're familiar with HTTP-requests, right? It's kinda the way the web it built. A webhook is simply a POST request typically containing JSON, like this one, coming from your ERP-system:

```
{
  "sku" : "JU40000365",
  "price" : "29999",
  "stock" : "9"
}
```

It says: Product with SKU JU40000365 has changes - and they're included in the JSON.

**The power of Webhooks is that they're triggered by the source app**

Okay, I made that one up. But that's my understanding anyhow. The source detects a change - through whatever mechanism (event, polling, whatever), and triggers a webhook, if there is a webhook configured for that change.

It's the way PayPal tells your shop that the purchase of order 123 was successfully paid - or declined.

**How to accept incoming webhooks**

So, back to your question - atm. you have to create a plugin or module for Craft CMS in order to handle incoming Webhooks.

If you have a look at [Rias' Stripe Webhook Plugin for Craft](https://github.com/riasvdv/craft-stripe-webhooks/tree/master/src), you can easily build your own plugin for your specific purpose. Look specifically at [the controller](https://github.com/riasvdv/craft-stripe-webhooks/blob/master/src/controllers/DefaultController.php).

Also have a look at the Craft 3 documentation, [How to build a plugin](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html), which gives you what you need to scaffold and load a plugin into your Craft CMS repo.

I used [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) to create a scaffold for the plugin.

In finishing, you may ask why I can't simply just give you a zip-file with the finished plugin. My answer is that you'll be better off experimenting and learning this yourself.

Comment: from the future is amazing! :)

Comment: Yes, he is. If only I knew what he knows...

Comment: Agh. It's nitech from even further into the future. I had forgotten this answer and was led back by Google. Hope this two way integration comes to fruition now - and it's amazing what we (at least I) forget once a few years have passed.